# Drawing two lines simultaneously on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So my situation is as follows: I have a set of data, each entry has a maximum and a minimum number.

I am visualising this data with the help of a canvas. I am trying to loop over the data and create two lines, one for the minimum and one for the maximum. For one of the two this works fine, however I can't create two lines without looping over the data twice.

The function lineTo() simply draws a line from the last point where it left off. Using this means a single line would zigzag between the minimum and maximum values.

Is there a way to have two 'pens' drawing separate lines at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var Point = function(x,y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
}

drawLine(new Point(10,10),new Point(100,100),'red');
drawLine(new Point(60,10),new Point(150,150),'green');


function drawLine(stPoint, endPoint,color){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(stPoint.x,stPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(endPoint.x,endPoint.y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width='300' height='300'></canvas>
```

You can use [beginPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) to create new path. and close the Path using [closePath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath).

Answer (score 1):

Did you use context.moveTo() after drawing a line?
The reason it draws a line from where it left is because your canvas moved to a point (x1,y1) at line 2 and if you use lineTo() again without calling moveTo it will draw from x1,y1. So use moveTo() after dawing a line.
For example :

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.moveTo(10, 50);
ctx.lineTo(150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
ctx.lineTo(min_x1, min_y1);
ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
ctx.lineTo(max_x2, min_y2);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something for that in the Canvas API.

But you could follow next algorithm:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(line_1_x1, line_1_y1)
ctx.lineTo(line_1_x2, line_1_y2)
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath()

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(line_2_x1, line_2_y1)
ctx.lineTo(line_2_x2, line_2_y2)
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath()
```

Potentially you could wrap it in a function:

```
function drawLine(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
}
```

Complete example ([On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpu9L7sg/1/)):

```js
function drawLine(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

drawLine(ctx, 50, 100, 100, 200)
drawLine(ctx, 100, 50, 200, 100)
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
```